# jQuery filtering AJAX data and then replaceWith data

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am calling pages via AJAX in jQuery.

The content of these pages needs to be filtered so that i only grab a certain DIV class.  In this instance 'Section1'.

This filtered data needs to replace the same data on the current page in the DIV of the same class.

I currently have this but it is not really working for me:

```
$("#dialog_select").live('change', function() {

    //set the select value
    var $optionVal = $(this).val();

    //$(this).log($optionVal);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $optionVal,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            var $filteredData = $(data).filter('.Section1');

            $('.Section1').replaceWith($filteredData);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `filter()` would only return **top level** elements, are they not contained within anything in the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* your problem is likely here:

```
var $filteredData = $(data).find('.Section1');
$('.Section1').replaceWith($filteredData);
```

[`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) would only find top level elements in the response (if it's a page, that's `<html>`, and wouldn't have any results).  [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks for decendant elements.  Also keep in mind that if you have multiple `.Section1` elements, this won't behave as expected and will have some duplication going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky thing to do and I would recommend placing the data into something like a DOMParser or document.implementation.createDocument or MSXML.

```
if (window.DOMParser) {
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
}
else {
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async="false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(text); 
}
```

is a basic code example.  jQuery itself can filter on a selector with the load function.  http://api.jquery.com/load/  This however has several limitations such as not being able to filter on html, head, or body tags.  This is why the above method is safer.

Comment: He's not trying to filter on any of those elements, just the standard inside-the-`<body>` filter...seems like this is over-complication, at least to me.

Comment: Agreed.

Tried your suggestion Nick and it works really well.

Always greatful for otehr points of view though :)

Comment: Nick the only problem is if the content coming back is a full HTML page.  All the elements in the <head> and <body> will be on the same level and it can cause some massive confusion and incur unintended results.  

My answer wasn't given for simplicity.  In this case your answer is fine.